# Python urllib заголовки

Tags: python

Нужно достать информацию из заголовка. Заголовок взял так [www.info](http://www.info)()

> Server: nginx/0.8.54
> Date: Tue, 17 May 2011 16:06:35 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Connection: close
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> Pragma: no-cache
> Set-Cookie: sid=6957034190070305; domain=.[spaces.ru](http://spaces.ru); path=/

Мне нужно достать sid=6957034190070305 и присвоить его переменной.
Пробивал сделать list([www.info](http://www.info)()) - но в переменной оказываются только заголовки, т.е "Server", "Date", "Set-Cookie", без значений.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import urllib
www = urllib.urlopen('http://www.lenta.ru')
www.info().items()
[('date', 'Tue, 17 May 2011 17:13:04 GMT'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=windows-1251'), ('connection', 'close'), ('vary', 'Accept-Encoding'), ('server', 'Apache')]
www.info()['date']

>>>'Tue, 17 May 2011 17:13:04 GMT'

www.headers.items()
[('date', 'Tue, 17 May 2011 17:13:04 GMT'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=windows-1251'), ('connection', 'close'), ('vary', 'Accept-Encoding'), ('server', 'Apache')]
www.headers['date']

>>>'Tue, 17 May 2011 17:13:04 GMT'
```

Answer (score 2):

Могу подсказать для urllib2 (Python 2.7)

```
import urllib2  
www = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.ru')  
cookie_header = www.headers['Set-Cookie']
```

На выходе строка, из которой можно вырезать нужный вам параметр.

Comment: +1 за то, что опередил на 40 сек :)

Comment: взаимно:)

Answer (score 0):

Для python 3.x:

```
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.info.ru')
print(response.headers['Set-Cookie']) # Достаем куки из заголовка
```